# Excel vba- Get code of change worksheet event to work for newly copied range

Tags: excel, vba

Question is simple really. I have some code in the change event of a worksheet with an intersect command.I also have a button on the sheet which when clicked copies a range of cells (for which the code in the change event is written) to a new location in the same sheet.

Question is how do I get the code of the change event to work for the new range I just pasted with the macro of the button.

Edit:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C6:C30")) Is Nothing Then
        UnprotectSheet ActiveSheet

        If Not Target.Value = "" Then
            Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = Now()
        Else
            Target.Offset(0, -1).ClearContents
        End If

        ProtectSheet ActiveSheet
    End If
End Sub
```

Button code:

```
Sub Macro()

Range("B3:F3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("N3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Start by reading [ask]. Then show us what you already tried, or what is not working as it should be.

Comment: Instead of describing your code it's better to show your code. [Edit] your question and add your code please.

Comment: Thank you!I havent tried anything really because i dont know how to do it.what i need basically is code to be created for the new range of copied cells every time i use the macro to copy.the code i have on change event works for range B3:B30.then i need it to work for E3:E30 for instance,then H3:H30 etc depending on how many times someone uses the button to copy-paste the range. Edit: i will post the code in a while when i have access to the pc

Comment: @philipprd well you said "*I have some code in the change event*" so please show that code. So we at least have something to work with.

Comment: added code.thanks for formatting it,not really into it yet.It basically adds a timestamp of changes as you can see.

Comment: Can you add code for you button press as well.

Comment: @philipprd Is the new range connected with the old one (so we can extend the original range) or is it an additional range?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ its an additional range.if i use the macro to copy-paste i will need the change event to work for range I6:I30 also.if i use the macro again i will need it to work for O6:O30 etc.

Comment: @philipprd please no code in comments. Always [edit] the question to add code. That's pretty much unreadable now.

Comment: Well I cannot see how your button code is pasting to `I6:I30` and `O6:O30` in the next 100 years? I think you will need to write your question much more detailed and best show a screenshot of your sheet.

Comment: I think you re stuck in details.if we get the change event code to work for a new range no matter what this range is,i will make it work fine for me.question is can we get  the change event code to work dynamically for new ranges without predefining the ranges?

Comment: @philipprd no we can't, we need to workaround this, that's why I was asking all the details. Because details matter which approach to choose. As workaround I suggest using a named range to intersect in the `Worksheet_Change` event. And the button should add the new range to the named range eg with `Union()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to always add the new copied range in your button to a named range (`"MyName"` in this example) and then use that named range in the `Worksheet_Change` to intersect with:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("MyName")) Is Nothing Then
```

---

Use something like in the `Test` procedure below in your button macro to add the new copied range to the named range.

```
Public Sub Test()
    AddRangeToNamedRange "MyName", Selection 'instead of selection better specify a range
                                             'like Range("A1:C5")
    Debug.Print Range("MyName").Address 'shows which addresses are represented by the named range MyName
End Sub


'**
'* Adds a new range to an existing named range.
'* If the named range does not exist yet it adds a named range with the
'* given range name and the given range.
'*
Public Sub AddRangeToNamedRange(RangeName As String, AddNewRange As Range)
    Dim NamedRange As Range

    On Error GoTo NameDoesNotExists
    Set NamedRange = Range(RangeName) 'throws error if name does not exists
    On Error GoTo 0

    'add new range to the named range
    ThisWorkbook.Names(RangeName).RefersTo = Union(NamedRange, AddNewRange)

    Exit Sub
NameDoesNotExists:
    Err.Clear
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add RangeName, AddNewRange 'add the name (first time)
End Sub
```

This way the `Range("MyName")` always represents all copied ranges that were copied with your button.