# excel vba-new sheet change event being the same as in the original sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Consequently to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798842/excel-vba-get-code-of-change-worksheet-event-to-work-for-newly-copied-range) topic,i would like to know if there is a way for the macro/button to paste the range into a newly created sheet(easy).But i also need the change event code of the original sheet to work for the new sheet as well somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Change the Worksheet_Change event code in the worksheet's private code sheet to a Workbook_SheetChange event in the ThisWorkbook code sheet and remove the original Worksheet_Change.

Modify the new Workbook_SheetChange event code to handle *Sh* (worksheet) parameter(s) to handle both the original and the newly created worksheet.